# Change border width of the header's row only in Google Docs with AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs

I have added a table with Google AppScript to a document.

Now I would like to change the table's appearance.

My goal is to make the border width of every cell = 0 instead of the bottom line of my header's row.

This image shows the intended appearance:

[Intended Appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zJrn.png)

This is my code so far. How can I change the border width of my header row's bottom line?

```
function myFunction() {

  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();

  const cells = [
    ['Name', 'Anzahl', 'Größe', 'Bemerkung'], 
    ['James', '1 x', 'M', ''],
    ['Carl', '1 x', 'L', 'Noch nicht bezahlt']
  ]

  const table =  body.appendTable(cells)
  
}
```

Comment: You can’t. It’s all borders or none.

Comment: @TheWizEd Unfortunately, in the current stage, this goal cannot be achieved by Google Document service (DocumentApp). But, it seems that it can be achieved by Google Docs API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current stage, I think that your goal cannot be achieved by only Google Document service (DocumentApp). But, fortunately, when Google Docs API is used, your goal can be achieved. In this answer, I would like to propose a sample script for achieving your goal using Docs API. When your script is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

This script uses Google Docs API. So, [please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const cells = [
    ['Name', 'Anzahl', 'Größe', 'Bemerkung'],
    ['James', '1 x', 'M', ''],
    ['Carl', '1 x', 'L', 'Noch nicht bezahlt']
  ];
  const table = body.appendTable(cells);


  // I added the below script.
  const docId = doc.getId();
  const index = body.getChildIndex(table);
  doc.saveAndClose();
  const tableStart = Docs.Documents.get(docId).body.content[index + 1].startIndex;
  const temp = { width: { magnitude: 0, unit: "PT" }, dashStyle: "SOLID", color: { color: { rgbColor: { blue: 0 } } } };
  const requests = [
    {
      updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableStartLocation: { index: tableStart },
        tableCellStyle: { borderTop: temp, borderBottom: temp, borderLeft: temp, borderRight: temp },
        fields: "borderTop,borderBottom,borderLeft,borderRight"
      }
    },
    {
      updateTableCellStyle: {
        tableRange: {
          tableCellLocation: { tableStartLocation: { index: tableStart }, rowIndex: 0, columnIndex: 0 }, rowSpan: 1, columnSpan: cells[0].length
        },
        tableCellStyle: {
          borderBottom: { dashStyle: "SOLID", width: { magnitude: 1, unit: "PT" }, color: { color: { rgbColor: { red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0 } } } }
        },
        fields: "borderBottom"
      }
    }
  ];
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, docId);
}
```

#### Testing:

When the above script is run, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### References:

- [Method: documents.get](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/get)
- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateTableCellStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetablecellstylerequest)

Comment: thank you for this script.  In the past I had tried to accomplish this manually without success.  And there are no methods in the Document Service.  I intend to keep this script handy for future use.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thank you for your comment. I would like to believe that this will be able to be used with Google Document service (Document App) in the future update.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you for your great solution. I have one additional question: How can I turn the first row to bold letters?

Comment: @Karl About your new question of `I have one additional question: How can I turn the first row to bold letters?`, I would like to support you. But the issue of replying is new issue, and that is different from your question. So can you post it as new question? Because when your initial question is changed by comment, other users who see your question are confused. By posting it as new question, users including me can think of it. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to resolve your new question?